# Is it possible to make Windows go from sleep to hibernate after a given period, like a MacBook?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, hibernate, power-management

If I remember it correctly, a MacBook first goes into sleep mode so that it can be quickly resumed if the user opens the lid again in a short time. But it automatically goes into hibernation mode from sleep, if the user does not open the lid for a long time.

Now, I know Windows use hybrid sleep that does both sleep and hibernation at the same time. I think this is not so efficient. It takes a very long time to go to sleep (because hibernation takes time), and it probably consumes more energy (to write all the memory content to the disk). If I closed the lid by mistake and try to open it right away, I would have to wait until the hybrid sleep process completes. If I disable hibernate sleep, then the computer goes into S3 sleep right away, and resumes quickly if I re-open the lid right away.

But can Windows be configured to work as MacBook does? I did not want to use hibernation, but it seems with the recent versions of Windows, sleep mode drains the battery faster. So, basically if I open the computer in 2 days or so, often the battery is really low or even dead.

Comment: [hybrid sleep is off by default for laptops](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110510-00/?p=10703), so there will never be the case that it's hibernating shortly after closing the lid unless you changed some settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hibernation is enabled, then there are separate time settings for *Sleep* and *Hibernate* in the advanced *Power Options* dialog.

First, be sure hibernation *is* enabled. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and click `Yes` in the UAC dialog to get a CMD prompt as Administrator. Type `powercfg -h on` to turn on hibernation.

Then open the *Power Options* dialog, advanced settings, click on *Sleep* to expand it, and set the delay for *Sleep* (which uses some power) and *Hibernate*, which saves state to disk and shuts down.

[image: Advanced Sleep and Hibernate Settings]

That said, [some machines have a power drain in hibernation](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/huge-power-consumption-in-hibernate/8fb61821-e588-4ee0-96d8-a3703b23ce88), or worse, even if supposedly completely shut down. That drain has been blamed on wake-on-LAN, [Intel's Management Engine](https://communities.intel.com/thread/125469), etc.

Comment: Note: Many laptops allow you to disable Wake-on-LAN in the BIOS/UEFI Firmware menus, so if you have the 'power drain in hibernation' issue described at the end of this answer, you may want to try doing so.

Comment: But it's just a work around isn't it? If you want windows to go to hibernate 5min after starting sleep, you need to set Hibernate to 5min. But then it always will go into Hibernation after 5min if the laptop doesn't get used, right?

Comment: @Albin, Look at the times shown above which are set arbitrarily -- not 5 min.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yeah I know...  sorry, **image** the sleep is set to 100min for battery **and** after closing the laptop and hibernate is set to 5min for battery - what will happen then? I assume hibernate kick in 5min after you close the laptop but it will also kick in after 5min if you don't use the laptop (but it's still open), right?!

Comment: Above, on battery, it sleeps after 18 min. 72 min, *later*, it goes from *sleep* to *hibernate*.

Comment: Does that work without hybrid sleep (hibernation is enabled, of course)? I want the computer to go to sleep immediately, not taking tens of seconds writing memory to the disk. If so, this is the answer I was looking for.