# Laptop prompts for username and password after long sleep, not keeping open apps or files (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, sleep, thinkpad, credentials

I just got a new corporate laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad p15v Gen 2), and if I put the computer into sleep mode from the start menu or by closing the lid and then wake it again right after, it works as I expect: it prompts me for my password and when I supply that, it puts me back into my previous windows session with the apps/docs that were open before.

If I put it into sleep and leave it overnight, though, when I wake it it prompts me for both my username and password. When up put in my credentials, it puts me into a new windows session, without any of the apps or files that I had open before sleep.

It's not rebooting (I don't see the BIOS or Windows startup screens), so I can't figure out why it will keep my open apps and files for a short sleep, but won't keep them for a longer one. It's on constant AC power.

Any ideas?

Comment: See if it has been set for Hybrid sleep. Normal Sleep keeps open Windows and Apps on my Lenovo machines.  Also, since new, contact Lenovo Support to see if something needs to be reconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have been caused by a setting in the sign-in area. When I toggle Restart Apps to "on" it works as expected, when either choosing sleep manually or closing the laptop lid. When I wake it again, it prompts for only my password (not username) and resumes the apps/docs I was working on before sleeping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows' [Sleep](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-pc-2941d165-7d0a-a5e8-c5ad-8c972e8e6eff) continuously uses power, albeit less than when Windows is running full-tilt. By leaving it on, in Sleep, overnight, you drain the battery to the point where the system must shut down completely. Evidently, the power options are set so *very little* power is left in the battery, and the laptop abruptly shuts down, without [saving the system state (i.e., Hibernate)](https://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/) to the drive.

That is bad for a few reasons:

1. Draining the battery that much, even when promptly recharged, severely reduces the battery service life. Rather than lasting years, the battery may require replacement in a matter of some weeks.
2. Abruptly shutting down due to very low power may cause errors on the drives, leading to damage to the OS, requiring repair or reinstallation.
3. It's also a nuisance to the user, who loses any work in progress.

For extended inactivity, use Hibernate, not Sleep. Also, [set Power Options to shut down *via* Hibernate](https://superuser.com/questions/1345622/is-it-possible-to-make-windows-go-from-sleep-to-hibernate-after-a-given-period) when the battery level drops to no less than 20% (I prefer an even larger margin, to extend battery service life).

*Caveat*: on some laptops, whether in Hibernate or even completely shut down, there is *still* a steady power drain! Whether due to wake-on-LAN, security firmware, or battery charge balancing, this can leave the battery dead after a month or two of shutdown. The only solution for this issue appears to be removing the battery where possible, or improvising a power switch to all leads of the battery (non-trivial).

Comment: Lots of great info here, but I don't think it's related to battery capacity/power drain, since it happens when the laptop is plugged in, and when I open the lid and log in, it shows battery at 100%. The computer isn't fully shut down (it doesn't have to boot up when I open the lid the next morning), but it does end my windows session and puts me into a new one. Any idea why, even when powered, it would end my windows session overnight?